# paramMap Angular error with params and route but everething seems fine

Tags: angular

I am doing this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4cmvjv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Fcountry-details%2Fcountry-details.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Fpages-routing.module.ts

in my Visual Studio Code and I have a problem with paramMap.
Everything is the same but i have an error:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'ParamMap' has no index signature. Did you mean to call 'get'?ts(7052)
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'ParamMap' has no index signature. Did you mean to call 'get'?

22       let name = this.route.snapshot.paramMap['params']['name'];